# Scala filter out rows where any column2 matches column1

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, filter, apache-spark-sql

Hi Stackoverflow,

I want to remove all rows in a dataframe where column A matches any of the distinct values in column B. I would expect this code block to do exactly that, but it seems to remove values where column B is null as well, which is weird since the filter should only consider column A anyway. How can I fix this code to perform the expected behavior, which is remove all rows in a dataframe where column A matches any of the distinct values in column B.

```
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(

      (scala.math.BigDecimal(1) , null),

      (scala.math.BigDecimal(2), scala.math.BigDecimal(1)),

      (scala.math.BigDecimal(3), scala.math.BigDecimal(4)),

      (scala.math.BigDecimal(4), null),

      (scala.math.BigDecimal(5), null),

      (scala.math.BigDecimal(6), null)

    ).toDF("A", "B")



// correct, has 1, 4

val to_remove = df

    .filter(

    df.col("B").isNotNull

    ).select(

    df("B")

).distinct()





// incorrect, returns 2, 3 instead of 2, 3, 5, 6

val final = df.filter(!df.col("A").isin(to_remove.col("B")))



// 4 != 2

assert(4 === final.collect().length)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isin` function accepts a list. However, in your code, you're passing `Dataset[Row]`. As per documentation https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@isin%28scala.collection.Seq%29
it's declared as

`def isin(list: Any*): Column`

You first need to extract the values into Sequence and then use that in `isin` function. Please, note that this may have performance implications.

```scala
scala> val to_remove = df.filter(df.col("B").isNotNull).select(df("B")).distinct().collect.map(_.getDecimal(0))
to_remove: Array[java.math.BigDecimal] = Array(1.000000000000000000, 4.000000000000000000)

scala> val finaldf = df.filter(!df.col("A").isin(to_remove:_*))
finaldf: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [A: decimal(38,18), B: decimal(38,18)]

scala> finaldf.show
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                   A|                   B|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|2.000000000000000000|1.000000000000000000|
|3.000000000000000000|4.000000000000000000|
|5.000000000000000000|                null|
|6.000000000000000000|                null|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Change filter condition `!df.col("A").isin(to_remove.col("B"))` to `!df.col("A").isin(to_remove.collect.map(_.getDecimal(0)):_*)`

Check below code.

```
val finaldf = df
.filter(!df
         .col("A")
         .isin(to_remove.map(_.getDecimal(0)).collect:_*)
       )

scala> finaldf.show
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                   A|                   B|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|2.000000000000000000|1.000000000000000000|
|3.000000000000000000|4.000000000000000000|
|5.000000000000000000|                null|
|6.000000000000000000|                null|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```